# Chaplin Backbone framework - views - how to use initialize and render methods?

Tags: backbone.js, chaplinjs

I need to execute some code both on initialize and render methods, but as I understand, I canot just modfy them directly when using Chaplin - when I define my own initialize method, my routes stop working.

I also tried afterInitialize() but it seems its not meant to be overrided: https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/issues/168#issuecomment-8015915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but as I understand, I canot just modfy them directly when using
>   Chaplin

You *can* modify them directly as long you appropriately delegate to the extended prototype.

As you haven't tagged your question `javascript` or `coffeescript`, the following are two solutions for each one. First up is javascript. Notice how we must explicitly invoke the extended function.

```
var View = Chaplin.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    // Add code here ..

    // The below invokes the initialize function of the
    // base Chaplin.View class in the context of 
    // this class
    Chaplin.View.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments);

    // .. or here
  }
});
```

Next is `coffeescript`, which makes this kind of thing significantly easier.

```
class View extends Chaplin.View
  initialize: ->
    // Add code here ..

    // The below auto-magically invokes the 
    // initialize method of the base class
    super

    // .. or here
```

Comment: Ah, so I just create my own initialize method and call the Chaplin's initialize method from within. Got it, thanks :)